# React use .push to add to an array with onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to add to my existing array which is called players (which is an external file "players.js" that's imported into my parent).

I can write:

```
 players.push({
  name: 'Maul',
  id: 26
});
```

And that works as ID is used for the key and the name is updated in the array.

However if I write

```
   handleAddPlayer = () => {
    console.log('i am working');
    players.push({
      name: 'Maul',
      id: 26
    });
  };
```

And on my button I have

```
    <div>
      <h4>Add A Player</h4>
      <input />
      <button onClick={this.handleAddPlayer}>Press to Add Player</button>
    </div>
```

And my state is as follows:

```
  this.state = {
  id: players.id,
  totalScore: 0,
  countInfo: [],
  evilName: '',
  color: '#6E68C5',
  scoreColor: '#74D8FF',
  fontAwe: 'score-icon',
  incrementcolor: '',
  scoreNameColor: 'white',
  glow: '',
  buttonStyle: 'count-button-start',
  players,
};
```

It does not work.

From here I have two questions:

1. why won't it update when I click the button but works before not as a function?
2. I would like to put a name into the input and generate a unique key that's added into my array, players.js

I've tried concatenate and had not a lot of success.

Comment: can you tell us the error you get? Isn't it "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"?

Comment: I don't get an error at all it's that nothing happens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Players is a property on the state object, so you'll want to call setState to update the property:

```
handleAddPlayer = () => {
  // create a clone of your array of players; don't modify objects on the state directly
  const players = this.state.players.slice(0);

  players.push({
    name: 'Maul',
    id: 26
  });

  this.setState({
    players: players,
  });
};
```

Comment: ok that worked like a charm and I learned a lot too, so thank you!  

Would you perchance be able to help me understand how the `<input>` can pass the value into the name and `id` can be a unique number?

Comment: wait, I got the random #, figured that out.  now just passing the value from `<input>` into the `name: ` area

Comment: Take a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components, one way to do it is to add a property on the state such as `value` that maintains the value of the text input, then update your input to `<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />`.

Then your handleAddPlayer method can simply look at this.state.value to extract the value in the input box.