# add and remove item in array on click reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm working on a simple table using reactjs and ant design.

My plan is to add and remove a new item on the list on button click.

My problem is I don't know how to do that.

I tried to follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992504/react-use-push-to-add-to-an-array-with-onclick) but no luck.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

[sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/wwxm61lo95)

```
function remove() {
  console.log("remove");
}
function add() {
  console.log("add");
}

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Num",
    dataIndex: "num"
  },
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address"
  }
];
const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    num: 1,
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    num: 2,
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    num: 3,
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  }
];

<Table pagination={false} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
    <Button type="primary" onClick={add}>
      add
    </Button>
    <Button type="danger" onClick={remove}>
      remove
    </Button>
```

Comment: for add new item in array use push & remove item from array use splice method for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use react [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). State holds the data, when you want to `add` or `remove`, update this state and react with re-render the table.

I have updated your code. On click of `add` a new random row is added. On click of remove last row is removed.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pj7oz8jrj7)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Button } from "antd";

function remove() {
  console.log("remove");
}
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Num",
    dataIndex: "num"
  },
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address"
  }
];
let data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    num: 1,
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    num: 2,
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    num: 3,
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  }
];

export default class MyTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: data
    };
  }
  add = () => {
    var row = {
      key: "99",
      num: 99,
      name: "I am New",
      age: 32,
      address: "New Address"
    };
    var newStateArray = [...this.state.data];
    newStateArray.push(row);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        data: newStateArray
      };
    });
  }

remove = () => {
  var newStateArray = [...this.state.data];
  if(newStateArray.length > 1) {
    newStateArray.pop();
  }
  this.setState(() => {
    return {
      data: newStateArray
    };
  });
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table
          pagination={false}
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={this.state.data}
        />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.add}>
          add
        </Button>
        <Button type="danger" onClick={this.remove}>
          remove
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyTable />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: `pop` will pop out least element, which I think OP don't want. He should have some index going with an element while removing.

Comment: there's a problem sir, when I tried to add `A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.` and the remove button is not working

Comment: @Manoj the example should let him understand the basics and get going.

Comment: hi sir, how can I make the numbers  increment?